# XCode Theme to Notepad++?

Tags: c++, xcode, notepad++

Is is possible to convert a Xcode theme to a Notepad++ theme?

The theme I want for Notepad++ is the Ego Theme found here: 
[Original EGO Theme](http://developers.enormego.com/view/ego_xcode_theme_for_xcode_4_egov2)

Except I would like it to work for C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't heard of any converters around, for any editor/IDE for that matter. I just do it manually, but maybe only because I'm patient enough.